# Javascript Template Generator

Tags: javascript, template-engine

I am working with dashboard kind of Java web application and it has multiple dashlets. Each dashlet is a javascript template. At the moment I am thinking of using mustache.js, handlerbar.js or dust.js.

Each of these dashlet should based on database view and it should render the content of each column in the view. There for I can not just have static templates, it should change depend on the structure of the view.

Is there any dynamic javascript template generator modules written in java?

Thanks,
Keth